# Texture and Pattern generator, Alternative to fireworks

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, adobe-flash, adobe

I use Adobe Fireworks for its Texture and Pattern tools to make things like this:

[image]

and then i copy-paste it to Flash Professional to use there.
but fireworks is so slow and buggy

is there a free or commercial alternative to do this simple Texture / Pattern thing easily?

1. Texture (like the second image above)
2. Patter and Texture (like the first one)
3. Transparent Texture, so the background would be instead of the white lines in second image
4. The ability to copy and paste it (as PNG 32 or any alpha transparent image) so i don't have to save it first and then import it to flash

*** I Use Mac OS X 10.8.4 ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found GIMP

[Download Here](http://www.gimp.org/)

it is free and useful

if anyone have any other suggestion i would be glad to hear it